# Pie Chart: What CSS value is required for a 277deg pie

Tags: javascript, html, css, webkit

I am trying to create this pie graph(on the left) using CSS. My attempt is on the right:

[image: What I want to achieve]
[image]

I can get it almost exact except for the correct chunk portion being taken out. **What are the correct clip values I need to get the pie chart to show only 277 degrees?**

I read on the CSS site that clip will be able to take other values instead of rect in the future(no sure how old the webpage was though) so maybe instead of using **clip: rect(..);** I can use something like **clip: ellipse(277deg);**?

*Also the border is not showing for the inside of the chunk, is there a CSS way I can get this to show?*

Here is the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8LecX/1/

Here is the simple code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<style>

.myPie {
    position:absolute;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    -moz-border-radius:100px;
    -webkit-border-radius:100px; 
    border-radius:100px; 

    clip:rect(0px,100px,200px,0px);
    /*-moz-transform:rotate(109.44deg); 
    -webkit-transform:rotate(109.44deg); 
    -o-transform:rotate(109.44deg); */

    background-color: RGB(0,153,255);
    border: solid 3px RGB(221,255,100);
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="myPie">
  </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You haven't mentioned SVG, have you considered it and ruled it out?

Comment: @bennedich SVG what is that exactly do you have a link to an example?

Comment: SVG is Scalable Vectors Graphics which is expressed in the XML format. In modern browsers SVG can be embedded inside HTML and animated with Javascript. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/QbRFf/

Comment: I don't think you can do this with `clip` alone (or if it's even useful). The only shape is `rect`angle currently. You seem to know this, so doesn't that make the question itself invalid? You're asking how to do something specific that doesn't exist (yet). If you want CSS pie charts, there are plenty of resources for that, but how do you expect the question of "What are the correct clip values" to be answerable?

Comment: What about using canvas?

Answer (score 0):

To make pies in css above 50% you must either draw an underlying circle any lay the pieces on top of it or you must remove the clip and add a second piece as a filler. I've elected to use the second option.

Here is an example of how this is done:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<style>
.hold {
position:absolute;
width:200px;
height:200px;
clip:rect(0px,200px,200px,100px);
left:300px;
}
.pie {
position:absolute;
width:200px;
height:200px;
clip:rect(0px,100px,200px,0px);
-moz-border-radius:100px;
-webkit-border-radius:100px; 
border-radius:100px; 
}
.hold.gt50 {
clip:rect(auto, auto, auto, auto);
}
.pie.fill {
-moz-transform:rotate(180deg) !important;
-webkit-transform:rotate(180deg) !important;
-o-transform:rotate(180deg) !important;
transform:rotate(180deg) !important;
}
#data1 {
margin-left:10px;
margin-top:10px;
}
#data1 .pie {
background-color:blue;
border-color:blue;
-moz-transform:rotate(277deg); 
-webkit-transform:rotate(277deg); 
-o-transform:rotate(277deg);
transform:rotate(277deg);
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="data1" class="hold gt50">
<div class="pie"></div>
<div class="pie fill"></div></div></body></html>
```